# Break nested flex div on mobile phones

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7pkcmg9/)

I have 2 main sections in each row, each section has an image and some text. How can I split these sections in new line on media query for mobile phones? If I put `display-direction: column;` on `.row-flex` then image AND text will also break and I don't want that. I want them to split like it is in image

[image: SS]

```css
.row-flex {
  display: flex;
}
.col-1 {
  flex: 1;
}
.col-2 {
  flex: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-flex">

  <a href="#" class="col-1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90">
  </a>

  <div class="col-2">
    <p>text text text text text text text text</p>
  </div>


  <a href="#" class="col-1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90">
  </a>

  <div class="col-2">
    <p>text text text text text text text text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such `display-direction: column`, what you are looking for is:  `flex-direction: column`, and you need to wrap the elements to make them `display:flex` in a row

```css
.row-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.col-1,
.col-2 {
  display: flex
}
.col-1 div {
  flex: 1;
}
.col-2 div {
  flex: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-flex">
  <div class="col-1">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90">
    </a>
    <div>
      <p>text text text text text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90">
    </a>
    <div>
      <p>text text text text text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```